# Combining two COUNT totals without common field

Tags: mysql

I am looking for some advice on the best way to combine the total of two COUNTs which come from different tables, using fields from each table which DO NOT have a common field name.

At the moment I have two separate queries which are able to count appearances and substitutions, as below.

### Appearances

```
SELECT
  P.PlayerID AS id, COUNT(A.AppearancePlayerID) AS apps
FROM 
  sports_seasons S
LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_players P ON P.PlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND S.SeasonID = '$seasonid'
LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_appearances A ON A.AppearancePlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND A.AppearanceSeasonID = '$seasonid'
WHERE 
  P.PlayerID != ''
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

### Substitutions

```
SELECT
   P.PlayerID AS id, COUNT(SU.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn) AS subapps
FROM 
   sports_seasons S
LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_players P ON P.PlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND S.SeasonID = '$seasonid'
LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_substitutions SU ON SU.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn = S.SeasonPlayerID AND SU.SubstitutionSeasonID = '$seasonid'
WHERE 
  P.PlayerID != ''
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

My current attempt is as follows:

```
SELECT P.PlayerID AS id,    
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(A.AppearancePlayerID) AS apps
  FROM 
    sports_seasons S
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_players P ON P.PlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND S.SeasonID = '$seasonid'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_appearances A ON A.AppearancePlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND A.AppearanceSeasonID = '$seasonid'
  WHERE 
    P.PlayerID != '' AND P.PlayerPublish != 0
  )
  +
  ( 
  SELECT
    COUNT(SU.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn) AS subapps
  FROM 
    sports_seasons S
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_players P ON P.PlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND S.SeasonID = '$seasonid'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_substitutions SU ON   SU.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn = S.SeasonPlayerID AND SU.SubstitutionSeasonID = '$seasonid'
  WHERE 
    P.PlayerID != '' AND P.PlayerPublish != 0               
  ) AS total
FROM sports_players P
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

Sadly, I've got no where.

Below are the tables in use. The DB is a record of player appearances for a sports team.

```
PlayerID | PlayerName // Players table

AppearanceID | AppearancePlayerID | AppearanceSeasonID // A table collating first team appearance made

SubstitutionID | SubstitutionPlayerIDIn | SubstitutionSeasonID // A table collating substitution appearances made

SeasonID | SeasonPlayerID // A table handling registrations
```

Using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the results of the two queries using them as derived tables. I think that an INNER JOIN suffices.

```
SELECT a.id as id, apps + subapps as total
FROM 
(
SELECT
  P.PlayerID AS id, COUNT(A.AppearancePlayerID) AS apps
FROM 
  sports_seasons S
LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_players P ON P.PlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND S.SeasonID = '$seasonid'
LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_appearances A ON A.AppearancePlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND A.AppearanceSeasonID = '$seasonid'
WHERE 
  P.PlayerID != ''
GROUP BY P.PlayerID
) as a 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT
   P.PlayerID AS id, COUNT(SU.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn) AS subapps
FROM 
   sports_seasons S
LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_players P ON P.PlayerID = S.SeasonPlayerID AND S.SeasonID = '$seasonid'
LEFT OUTER JOIN sports_substitutions SU ON SU.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn = S.SeasonPlayerID AND SU.SubstitutionSeasonID = '$seasonid'
WHERE 
  P.PlayerID != ''
GROUP BY P.PlayerID
) as b on a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.id;
```

Comment: Thank you - but getting a syntax error on:

check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'full outer join ( SELECT P.PlayerID AS id, COUNT(SU.Substitut

Comment: I am sorry, I am looking at it now. Basically the problem is that MySql does not support full joins, so some rewriting is in order.

Comment: I updated my answer, after some experimenting I understand that `inner join ` is sufficient.

Comment: And I brought back then `'$seasonid'` variable :-)

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x`